# awk/sed: append counters to multiple different strings

Tags: awk, sed

I have a text file, and would like to append a counter to a number of different strings of interest. An example `infile`:

```
string_of_interest
abcd
efgh
another_string_of_interest
ijkl
abcd
another_string_of_interest
mnop
wxyz
string_of_interest
ijkl
wxyz
another_good_string
abcd
efgh
another_string_of_interest
```

As you can see there are multiple strings to ignore, some of which might repeat, but I only want to count repeats for a subset of strings to produce an `outfile` like this:

```
string_of_interest_1
abcd
efgh
another_string_of_interest_1
ijkl
abcd
another_string_of_interest_2
mnop
wxyz
string_of_interest_2
ijkl
wxyz
another_good_string_1
abcd
efgh
another_string_of_interest_3
```

Note the counter is appended as part of each string using snake case.

I've fumbled around with `sed` and `awk` to try, but I'm so novice I'm nowhere close yet. Any recommendations?

Comment: `sed` is notoriously bad at counting, you you probably want to use `awk` or some other language with support for arithmetics.

Comment: Could you ever have two strings of interest, `A` and `A_1` (or `A_n`, for some positive integer `n`)?

Comment: Please read [how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65621325/how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern) to understand why this matters and then [edit] your question to include a target string that contains regexp metachars and is a substring of other strings in your input so we can see how those should be handled. For example use `t.*e` as the "string" and include lines with `the` and `at.*en` in your input as well as the real target string `foo_t.*e_bar`.

Answer (score 3):

if all those line with your interested string contains a key string like *`"string"`*, you could do:

```
awk '/string/{ $0=$0 "_" ++seen[$0] }1' infile
```

otherwise use below code, that is for each line that matches the corresponding string of interest appends an incrementing counter for it.

```
awk '
    $0 == "string_of_interest" ||
    $0 == "another_string_of_interest" ||
    $0 == "another_good_string" { $0=$0 "_" ++seen[$0] } 1
' infile
```